# Image Bitmap landmark detection without using google play services?

Tags: android, face-detection

I need to develop a sample demo app in which I have to detect bitmap image landmark like nose, eyes, lips etc, without using google play service i.e I don't want to use mobile vision please [refer this](https://developers.google.com/vision/) to detect image landmark. Please provide an alternative to this. Need free library not paid like face++ Android SDK.